# how to use pangination and sortByDesc fuction in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i tried to use pagination in my laravel view i got this problem

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist. (View: C:\wamp\www\project\resources\views\demmande\demmandes.blade.php)

here is my controller function

```
public function ViewDemmandes(){
    $listdemmande=Demmande::paginate(10)->sortByDesc('created_at');
    $listvillee=Ville::all();
    $listcategorie=Categorie::all();

    $villes = $listvillee;
    $demmande = $listdemmande;
    $categorie = $listcategorie;

    return view("demmande.demmandes",compact('villes','categorie','demmande'));
}
```

but when i delete sortByDesc function like this

```
public function ViewDemmandes(){
    $listdemmande=Demmande::paginate(3);
    $listvillee=Ville::all();
    $listcategorie=Categorie::all();

    $villes = $listvillee;
    $demmande = $listdemmande;
    $categorie = $listcategorie;

    return view("demmande.demmandes",compact('villes','categorie','demmande'));
}
```

it works fine please can you help me resolve this problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `->paginate(10)` will return an instance of [LengthAwarePaginator](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html). Which implements all the methods the [Collection](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html) has (`->sortByDesc()` being one of them). But calling a collection method will return the underlying collection, not an instance of paginator.

So in your case you're overriding the paginator with the collection being returned from `->sortByDesc()`.

Sort with SQL instead of on a collection:

```
$listdemmande = Demmande::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
// Or using `->latest()` shorthand:
// $listdemmande = Demmande::latest()->paginate(10);
```

If there's a reason why you want to sort after fetching the query, you could override just the paginators underlying collection:

```
$listdemmande = Demmande::paginate(10);
$listdemmande->setCollection($listdemmande->sortByDesc('created_at'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this in controller

$listdemmande=Demmande::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

And also don't forget to add in blade view to add this ...

After foreach add to this

> {{$listdemmande->links()}}

Your links error is solve.

Comment: This won't work as the Eloquent query doesn't have a method `sortByDesc`

Comment: yes is not work like this but it work like this 

$data= Product::get()->sortByDesc('created_at');