# Laravel sortByDesc and Paginate on a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I paginate the result here and keep the sort order.

```
public function show(Language $language)
{
    $questions = Question::with(['translations' => function($q) use ($language) {
        $q->where('language_id', $language->id);
    }])->get()->sortByDesc('translations');

    return view('language.show', compact('questions', 'language'));
}
```

Right now if I try to paginate by doing this, I get an error saying:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::sortByDesc()

```
$questions = Question::with(['translations' => function($q) use ($language) {
    $q->where('language_id', $language->id);
}])->sortByDesc('translations')->Paginate(20);
```

I also tried this from this post: [how to use pangination and sortByDesc fuction in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309247/how-to-use-pangination-and-sortbydesc-fuction-in-laravel)

```
$questions = Question::with(['translations' => function($q) use ($language) {
    $q->where('language_id', $language->id);
}])->Paginate(20);
$questions->setCollection($questions->sortByDesc('translations'));
```

This sort of works because I get the paginated results in  a sorted order but it's not what I want. I want all the questions to be first sorted by whether they have translations or not and then paginated.

Note, translations is not a column, it's just the result of the query so I can't use SQL as suggested in the post I linked.

The relationship in question model.

```
public function translations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\QuestionTranslation');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ordering the relationship will have no effect on the order of the main model. Relationships are retrieved via a second query which happens after the main model is retrieved.

You can `join` however:

```
public function show(Language $language)
{
    $questions = Question::selectRaw('questions.*, translations.id')
         ->leftJoin('translations', function ($join) use ($language) {
              $join->on('questions.id', '=', 'translations.question_id') 
                   ->andOn('translations.id', '=', $language->id);
              })
         ->orderBy('translations.id') // NULLs should appear last
         ->paginate(20);

    return view('language.show', compact('questions', 'language'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying. This is not really what I want. I want to order by whether questions has a translation or not. I don't have a field for that to check against in the question_translations table. I updated my question to show you the relationship. In the first part of my code which I have the sort, I get the result sorted correctly, I just can't use pagination.

Comment: @HamidHosseini you can modify it slightly to use `leftJoin` rather than `join` and rely on the fact that the translation fields will be null if they don't match. Not tested it myself but it might work. Check update

Comment: Then you need to create your custom pagination, and pass the ordered results to it.

Comment: @mohammad.kaab How can I do that?

Comment: Check this gist, https://gist.github.com/mkdesignn/db7f1b7759b95a3acd0dd9fa41edceba

Answer (score -1):

```
private $limit = 10;

public function show(Language $language)
{

    $questions = Question::with(['translations' => function($q) use ($language) {
              $q->where('language_id', $language->id);
          }]);
    $data = $questions->paginate($this->limit);

    $data->sortByDesc('translations');

    return view('language.show', $data);
}
```